# Entity framework multiple where based on if not being added

Tags: entity-framework

```
  Using _webDataDBContext As New WebDataEntities()
            Dim results = _webDataDBContext.coverageareas.Select(Function(x) x)

            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(city) = False Then
                results.Where(Function(x) x.City = city)
            End If

            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(county) = False Then results.Where(Function(x) x.County = county)

            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(state) = False Then results.Where(Function(x) x.State = state)

            If String.IsNullOrEmpty(zip) = False Then results.Where(Function(x) x.Zip = zip)

            Return Await results.ToArrayAsync()
        End Using
```

Not sure why this isn't working, when my if statements are satisfied I want to append a where statement to my results.

However these where's are not being added even though the statements are satisfied. Anyone know why?

Comment: im dumb, I need to put results = statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign the Where statement to the IQueryable.

```
results = results.Where(...)
```

Comment: Can't believe i missed that haha